# How to use props for a list in React Native?

Tags: image, list, react-native

I want to take a list of images and send it to another file that will use a list to list the images.

So in my main file I have this:

```
render(){
return(
  <ScrollView>

  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
     <View>
      <ImageList images={require('./images/example1.jpg'), require('./images/example2.jpg')}/>
     </View>
  </View>

  </ScrollView>
);
```

}

Then in another file I have this:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
this.state = {
  dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows([
    props.images
  ])
};

 }

render() {
return (
  <View>
    <ListView
      contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
      dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
      renderRow={(rowData) => <Image source={rowData} style={styles.imageSize}/>}
    />
  </View>
);
```

}

The problem is that only one of the images is displayed. I want all the images to display.

I tried converting it to an array:

```
  <ImageList images={[require('./images/example1.jpg'), require('./images/example2.jpg')]}/>
```

But I get an error, which says:

```
JSON value '1' of type NSNumber cannot be converted to an image. Did you forget to call resolveAssetSource() on the JS side?
```

Made a change based on @Siou suggestion.

```
this.state = {dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(props.images)};
```

But I got an error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(dataBlob[sectionID])')
```

Comment: props.images is an array right?

Comment: Yes it is an array

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to resolve the asset source:

```
import {Image} from 'react-native'
Image.resolveAssetSource(asset)
```

For an array:

```
images={images.map(image => Image.resolveAssetSource(image))}
```